# Adding leading Zeros into Day and Month Value

Tags: powerquery

I have a simple table that has a column with a date in this format:
MM/DD/YYYY.
Unfortunately, there are some folks who are working without leading zeros.
Therefore I would like to add a leading zero into the Month and Day element using Power Query to have a common format.
But how? Does someone have any function to share?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you sure it's recognised as date (right click, change type, choose date). Once PQ recognises your source as date it'll format it according to your local.

Comment: This seems like an [XY](https://xyproblem.info) problem.  You can certainly change how the contents of a date column in Power Query is being displayed, by using either the `Date.ToText` or `DateTime.ToText` function as appropriate.  Your results will look as you describe, but they won't be **real** dates nor will they be interpreted as such in PQ.  Not sure how that helps your problem of *"some folks who are working without leading zeros"*.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : I missed the example. Sorry for that!. In the column there values like 01/01/2021 and 1/1/2021. How can I change them into 1 specific format with leading zeros? The column is a string/ text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, not sure why you want to do this, but

- Assuming all of the entries are text that looks like dates, you can use the following M-Code:
- Split the string on the delimiter
- Change each entry in the list to a number
- Add 2000 to the last number
- Change the numbers back to text with a "00" format
- Recombine with the delimiter

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],

//set type = Text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TextDate", type text}}),
 
    xform = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",
        {"TextDate", each 
            let 
                x = Text.Split(_,"/"),
                y = List.Transform(x,each Number.From(_)),
                z = List.ReplaceRange(y,2,1, {2000+y{2}}),
                a= List.Transform(z,each Number.ToText(_,"00")),
                b = Text.Combine(a,"/")
            in b}) 
in
    xform
```

[image]

*I am thinking a better solution might be to set up your data entry method so that all dates are entered as **dates** rather than text*

Comment: Ron Sir, may i ask one question on the above solution because i have tried this one and found success, but i want to know something else as well, if you please help?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That's not how this forum usually works. But go ahead and ask and, if it cannot be answered in a brief comment, I'll make a suggestion.

Comment: Ron Sir, apologize for the same, since it was related to this query only so i thought, Ok, so if the year is prior to 2000 like 1999 or 1985 or 1980 what should be placed instead of 2000 in the M-Code.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Huh? `1900`, of course

Comment: Sir, not like that, i mean its funny but if the data has both like 2000 and 1900 then how can it be made dynamic

Comment: Sir like you have hard coded 2000 so if there is year of 1985, then it will give error, but how to alter that within in the M-Code, might be i am wrong, if so please forgive me,

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya You use an `if` statement to check the value of the year.  And just like Excel does, you arbitrarily pick some dividing point. Something like *(pseudocode)*, `yr+1900 + (if (year<35) then 100 else 0)`

Comment: Alright Sir, thank you very much, i shall try the way you guided !